# Agents of Shield : Who is the banished inhuman from S03E08?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield, inhumans

I watched 18th Nov-2015's episode of *Agents of Shield* and in that it is revealed that

> there was a inhuman who was banished because of various reasons and Hydra's founding goal was to get him back.

Is there any reference to this in Marvel history as to who is this guy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Major spoilers!

This now has a canon answer.

> This is Hive, also known as Alveus.

> [image: Hive]

> In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, Hive served the Kree, and was designed to command the Inhuman armies

> However, his power grew too great, and he was banished to Malveth. 
>  Hive is a parasitic life form that possesses various powers, including
>  the ability to infest and possess corpses, to take over Inhumans and
>  twist their personalities to serve him, to consume others in order to
>  make himself stronger, and to kill ordinary humans, either by
>  stripping the skin from their bones or by infesting them from the
>  inside.

> As of Season 3 Episode 17, Hive inhabits the corpse of Grant Ward.

> There is an interesting similarity between Hive and Kilgrave from *Jessica Jones*, both of whom possess the ability to force others to do their will through infection, though on the one hand Hive can only affect Inhumans, whereas on the other hand Kilgrave cannot change his victims' personalities.

Comment: Hmm, should the picture be in spoiler tags too ? It's not the cast at the moment.

Comment: Well, I tried... I'll search question with spoiler images.

Comment: I got the image behind spoiler markup, and have tried to preserve your intended formatting. However, your answer is completely unreadable, which severely limits its usefulness; is there *any* part of this that can be de-spoilerified?

Comment: Maybe you should just unpoiler it then. If you click on the question, you probably want to see the answer..